# systemC installation visual studio 2015 visual studogets is not a member of std

Tags: visual-studio

im installing systemC on visual studio 2015, in my include i only use # include "systemc.h" when i debug i got this problem " gets is not a member of std" any help for solving it thanks

include "systemc.h"

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
 // Hello_world is module name
SC_MODULE(hello_world) {
SC_CTOR(hello_world) {
    // Nothing in constructor 
}
void say_hello() {
    //Print "Hello World" to the console.
    cout << "Hello World.\n";
}
};

  // sc_main in top level function like in C++ main
int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
hello_world hello("HELLO");
// Print the hello world
hello.say_hello();
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the line

```
using std::gets;
```

in systemc.h, because std::gets is deprecated and has been removed in vs2015.